# How do I write a regular expression that only matches if match three required capture groups

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'd like to match strings that are comprised of:

1. First Iniitial
2. Middle Name
3. Last Name + optional suffix (Jr. Sr. III, etc.)

and not match string that are comprised of a First Name + Last Name and suffix.

I have the following sample data:

```
H. Graham Motion
T. James Kelly
J. Palacios Moli
A. Chadwick Box
H. Graham Motion III
T. James Kelly, Jr.
H. Graham Motion II
V. Barboza Jr.
```

I would like to match all of the strings except the last.

Here is what I have for a regular expression:

```
^(\w\.)(\s\w+\s[\sI\,\sJSr.]{0,5})*(\w+[\sI\,\sJSr.]{0,5})$
```

but it not working.  You can see the regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/QPN3gz/1) at regex101.

Comment: The question is not clear... do you want to ignore the third group? You can do that with `(?:\w+[\sI\,\sJSr.]{0,5})$`

Comment: No, I only want to match names that are comprised of a first initial, middle name and last name with optional suffix.  In the sample data above, all the names meet that requirement except the last.   Is that more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tweaked your expression a bit and come up with `^(\w\.)\s(\w+)\s(\w+(?:,?\s(?:I{0,5}|Jr\.|Sr\.))?)$`. For the sake of sanity and clarity, I moved the `\s` out of the capture groups, since I assume you don't define a middle name as a string of word characters with a leading and trailing space. I *think* I kept the spirit of your definition of a last name + suffix.

#### (Very verbose) Explanation:

```
^                             start
(                             1st group (1st initial)
  \w\.                        one word char followed by a period
)
\s                            one whitespace char
(                             2nd group (middle name)
  \w+                         1 or more word chars
)
\s                            one whitespace char
(                             3rd group (last name + optional suffix)
  \w+                         1 or more word chars
  (?:                         non-capturing group (optional suffix)
    ,?                        0 or 1 commas
    \s                        one whitespace char
    (?:I{1,5}|Jr\.|Sr\.)      one of: 1-5 I chars, "Jr." or "Sr."
  )?                          match suffix group 0 or 1 times
)
$                             end
```

You'll notice I made the change from `I{0,5}` to `I{1,5}` because 0 characters doesn't seem like much of a suffix to me. However I don't see a lot of people with the suffix `IIII` or `IIIII` so you may want to change it to `I{0,3}|IV|V`. You may also want to change the optional comma after the last name to *require* it before Jr./Sr. and *disallow* it before a Roman numeral.

Also, remember that `\w` also matches underscores and digits! And that `\s` matches most whitespace characters, and not just a regular space.

Comment: Your regular express is working great, but I came across one instance that seems to trip it up.  Unfortunately, even with your great explanation I can't seem to find the right fix.  It does not seem to treat a Jr. or Sr. suffix the same as an II or III.  When I have this as a string:  C. McGaughey II - it fails an returns C. II. If I have this as a string: C. McGaughey Jr. it works and does not return a match. Why is that?

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor sorry I missed this; I was on vacation. It's because "II" matches the regex for a last name with no suffix. You'll have to be more specific with the definition of a last name (at the very least, it can't be I, II, III, IV, or V), perhaps by defining it as a capital letter followed by 1 or more lowercase letters.